# Get text from one th and add place to other th

Tags: jquery

I have two tables. script should get each th value/content from first table th and place to second table's corresponding th. Please help.

```
$("#mytable th").each(function(){
   var cellText = $(this).html();
    alert(cellText);       
    $(".demo th").text(cellText);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9ndcL/383/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `index`, to get target the specific `th` element with [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method

```
$("#mytable th").each(function(index) {
  var cellText = $(this).html();
  $(".demo th").eq(index).text(cellText);
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9631ecje/)

Comment: Beat me to it :) I did it slightly different way, but they all work: http://jsfiddle.net/9ndcL/384/